# Download the first 1000 bytes

Tags: c#, .net

I need to download a text file from the internet using C#. The file size can be quite large and the information I need is always within the first 1000 bytes. Is this possible?

Comment: Is _what_ possible? Downloading text files? Learn how to ask questions - http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: + 1 That should be the official FAQ page.

Comment: @Oded: What do you think is missing from the question?

Comment: +1 for 0XA3 - it's a very brief question but does supply enough information to be answered.

Comment: what's wrong with my questions?

Comment: For those wondering what the question is, read the title.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Stolen from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/ce0e2e13-ec2c-468f-beea-469acb2468fd).**

```
string GetWebPageContent(string url)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    HttpWebRequest request;
    const int bytesToGet = 1000;
    request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

    //get first 1000 bytes
    request.AddRange(0, bytesToGet - 1);

    // the following code is alternative, you may implement the function after your needs
    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 1000);
            Array.Resize(ref buffer, read);
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
        }

    }
}
```

(Edited as requested in the comments... ;) )

Comment: I would suggest replacing the `ReadToEnd` with a read of (at most) 1000 characters in case the server ignored the range request.

Comment: @Richard: That wouldn't be necessary since a range header was added to the request.  The response will be at most 1000 characters.

Comment: @Jeff: as my comment said "in case the server ignored the range request" as the `Range` header is *optional* for the server and can be ignored.

Comment: I have to agree with Richard. As per RFC http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35.2 the server *may* ignore the `Range` header, so that you should only read as much as you want and the close the connection.

Comment: @Rana the answer I provided is partially correct. It will work but as per @Richard's comment, the server might ignore the request, in which case you want to limit the StreamReader to only read the first 1000 characters. I'm not 100% sure how to implement that but someone else might have a solution. If anyone does know, please feel free to copy the code above and modify it, it wasn't really mine to begin with :)

Comment: thanks Marko. does anyone know how to do that? limit streamreader to only read the first 1000 characters?

Comment: Perhaps start a new question @Rana - and copy my code above as your work in progress.

Comment: @Timwi, you deserve at least half of the rep points for this answer. So I've just upvoted 4 of your ones. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I did this as an answer to your newer question. You could put the range header in too if you want, but I excluded it.

```
    string GetWebPageContent(string url)
    {
        //string result = string.Empty;
        HttpWebRequest request;
        const int bytesToGet = 1000;
        request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        var buffer = new char[bytesToGet];
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                sr.Read(buffer, 0, bytesToGet);
            }
        }
        return new string(buffer);
    }
```

Comment: Technically this may get up to 2000 bytes if the StreamReader "thinks" that it gets back unicode. My edit (see above) on the other hand forces the encoding, which may be wrong as well. Rama needs to clarify the requirement I guess.