# Download the first 1000 bytes of a file using C#

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Download the first 1000 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853495/download-the-first-1000-bytes)

I need to download a text file from the internet using C#. The file size can be quiet large and the information I need is always within the first 1000 bytes.

This is what I have so far. I found out that the server might ignore the range header. Is there a way to limit streamreader to only read the first 1000 characters?

```
string GetWebPageContent(string url)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    HttpWebRequest request;
    const int bytesToGet = 1000;
    request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

    //get first 1000 bytes
    request.AddRange(0, bytesToGet - 1);

    // the following code is alternative, you may implement the function after your needs
    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Yup. Exact same question from the same user, and an answer was accepted there

Comment: I posted some code that limits the stream read in your other question

Answer (score 3):

[**Please follow-up in your question from yesterday!**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853495/download-the-first-1000-bytes)

Answer (score 1):

There is a [read method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kstw824.aspx) that you can specify the number of characters to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the first 1000 bytes from the stream, then decode the string from the bytes:

```
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[bytesToGet];
        int count = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytesToGet);
        Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(response.Encoding);
        result = encoding.GetString(bytes, 0, count);
    }
}
```

Comment: That stream writes to a char[]

Comment: @Luke Schafer, what do you mean ? "that" stream is not different from any other stream. The Stream.Read method takes a byte[], not a char[]. Check the doc before you downvote...

Comment: You must be confusing with StreamReader.Read. I'm not using StreamReader here...

Comment: I was confusing it, my apologies. I mistook the surrounding code as being the same as the code in the OP. You are correct.

Comment: Please edit your answer slightly so I can unvote

Comment: I just did, I fixed a small mistake at the same time...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `request.AddRange()` which may be ignored by some servers as you said, read 1000 bytes (1 KB = 1024 bytes) from stream and then close it. This is like you get disconnected from server after receiving 1000 bytes. Code:

```
 int count = 0;
 int result = 0;
 byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
 // create stream from URL as you did above

 do
 {
     // we want to read 1000 bytes but stream may read less. result = bytes read
     result = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 1000); // Use try around this for error handling
     count += result;
 } while ((count < 1000) && (result != 0));
 stream.Dispose();
 // now buffer has the first 1000 bytes of your request
```

Comment: With that solution, if the response is shorter than 1000 bytes it will loop forever...